# Accounts.emailTemplates is undefined

Tags: meteor

Following the docs [here](http://auth-docs.meteor.com/#accounts_emailtemplates),  I'm trying to set the content of the `resetPassword` email template but I keep getting `undefined`.

When I inspect the `Accounts` object in the console, I see that indeed it doesn't have an `emailTemplates` property.

Code:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text = function(user, url) {
      url = url.replace('#/', '');
      return "Click this link to reset your password: " + url;
 }
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resetPassword' of undefined
```

Comment: Did you do "meteor add accounts-password"?

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue.  I create a new app, added accounts-password, and modified the default .js file, pasting your code example at the end.  It worked fine.  Do these steps work for you? Perhaps it's something specific to your app.

Comment: No. The exact same error repeats itself when I create another test app

Comment: what is the filename and directory where you put this code?

Comment: lib/emailTemplates.js

Comment: @Matanya Try a different dir than lib, files in lib are loaded before everything else.

Comment: The same thing happened to me as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up putting the code in the `server` directory, and then it worked flawlessly.
What baffles me is that the docs state this property is to be used `Anywhere`...